# Reading properties using reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reflection

In my C# WPF app, my MainViewModel is having this property:

```
public object CurrentViewModel
        {
            get { return m_currentViewModel; }
            set
            {
                m_currentViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
            }
        }
```

Let's say CurrentViewModel returns an instance class VMParent at runtime.

And my VMParent looks like this:

```
public class VMParent
{
 public object BaseViewModel
        {
            get { return m_baseViewModel; }
            set
            {
                m_baseViewModel = value;
            }
        }
}
```

And BaseViewModel property returns an instance of class VMBase at runtime which has certain number of properties.

Now, on click of a button in my MainViewModel.xaml, using reflection, I need to read values of all properties of CurrentViewModel and BaseViewModel.
I'm able to do so for CurrentViewModel but not for BaseViewModel.

Any pointers please?
Thanks.

```
Type sourceType = CurrentViewModel.GetType();            
PropertyInfo[] sourcePI= sourceType.GetProperties();
```

Comment: Why via reflection? What specific issue are you having? Why can't you do it for `BaseViewModel`? Why isn't `BaseViewModel` just a standard base class, instead of being contained by `CurrentViewModel`? This question is at best too broad, and really just not clear at all. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried so far, and explain precisely what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Answer (score 0):

I will illustrate this capability by printing the name of the property. Shown below following your following

```
foreach (var p in sourcePI)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    var nested = p.GetValue(CurrentViewModel).GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var n in nested)
    {
        WriteLine(n.Name);
        // you can continue to nest as you like
    }
}
```

You can keep propagating into the nest as many times as you want